# QGIS - Importing data as Delimited Text not CSV into Data Source Manager

Tags: excel, gis, qgis

I'm doing the QGIS 3.22 Beginner’s Guide on youtube.

Getting stuck trying to import the CSV data file.

The tutorials says to go to Data Source Manager > Delimited Text > File Format, then select Regular Expression delimiter.

The issue I have is that the CSV delimited file I created in Excel, automatically selects the CSV option but I need the *delimiter* option.

NB - when saving the file in Excel, I selected File > Save As > CSV (Comma delimited) as instructed.

But in QGIS, when I import and select Regular Expression delimiter, it doesn't take the commas into account, i.e. it shows one column instead of four columns.

The sample CSV file is over here. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_g10p7qL4nDBX1HmbD2RBtDS-m6wIfc6

It's minute 12 of this video. https://youtu.be/9seReuWjZUg

Any thoughts on how to get the delimited file to import correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool, but I'd think if you select `Regular Expression Delimiter` there will need to be a box where you can enter the **Regular Expression** you want to use.  The regex for a comma is `,`

Comment: Thanks Ron, yes, I can enter a comma in that field BUT in the video he specifically states to use a semi-colon. Talking to a friend in Brazil, he said ; is the default over there instead of ,. I think this is a genuine mistake in the video. Like you suggested, if I do use comma and select the CSV option, it works fine.

Comment: Or maybe the video merely assumes that you are Brazilian and using Brazilian windows regional settings.